# Proper usage of ContactsContract

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contactscontract

I have some struggles to find an up-to-date example how to properly handle ContactsContract to CRUD (create,read,update,delete) contacts. Most examples make use of "People", which is deprecated. Maybe I got just too much confused about the changes made, right now I don't know which way to choose.

The use of 'People' such as described at [developers.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) under 'Adding new values' should be avoided, as it is marked as deprecated, right?

Comment: You have an excellent tutorial here: http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/